# In Visual Studio, how can I maintain one project that references different versions of the same class library?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, class-library

Say I have a project that references version 1.0 of a class library. This class library is then updated and is now v. 2.0 (and it's not backwards compatible).

I'd like to be able to maintain the same project using both v. 1.0 and v. 2.0 of the class library. The reason is that these class libraries provide APIs for a specific hardware. Some of my customers are using hardware compatible with v. 1.0 only, and some are using hardware compatible with v. 2.0 only. The APIs differ in minor (but non-compatible) ways.

How can I maintain the same project while being able to "flip" back and forth between class libraries 1.0 and 2.0? I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017. Also, this is a .NET Framework project written in C#.

Comment: Use git branches?

Comment: @Amy I could, but I'd like to be able to use the same code. With git branches, I'd have to constantly merge changes from one branch into the other. I hope there's a more convenient way. Thanks.

Comment: Define flags for compiler to include one or the other and just switch configurations when needed?

Comment: Is your V1.0 and V2.0 code resides in same VS project?

Comment: @PankajKapare The class libraries are somewhere else. They're just DLLs provided by a third-party.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen How do I "include one or the other" in Visual Studio?

Comment: This is what [Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) is for.

Comment: As I said, compiler flags. You can conditionally define what code is compiled in. Or make two projects which include different files. Or use assemblies and interfaces.

Comment: @stephen.vakil It seems to me that Alias is used when I want to have both libraries at the same time. I want to be able to switch between them.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes, I can use compiler flags to run one piece of code or another. But how do I use compiler flags to reference one library or another? Thanks.

Comment: So you are going to build two different versions of the app then depending on customer hardware?

Comment: @stephen.vakil Yes. I want to create one version of my app that uses library 1.0, and another version of my app that uses library 2.0.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878581/Specify-Assembly-References-Based-On-Build-Configu) then?  But you still need additional steps in code, obviously, since the APIs are incompatible.

Comment: @stephen.vakil Yes, something like this. Thanks. And, yes, I can define different symbols depending on the configuration, and use them where the code differs.

Comment: Can you create a common interface that your application references and then a class library for each version of the hardware that implements the interface.  You application need not know what hardware it is communicating with.  It only calls methods defined on the interface.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes, but the app still needs to know which implementation to use.

Comment: I would think that would be set in a configuration file or settings menu or something that the user would pick which hardware they have.  Or perhaps, the application could auto-detect which hardware by attempting to send a command to it?